# Why is the output voltage DC? How can I make the output sinusoid?

Tags: operational-amplifier, design

In my design for an opamp, the output voltage is a constant value when I think it should have been a sinusoid. What can I do?

[image: OPAMP DESIGN USING BJT TRANSISTORS]

Comment: (I see power supplied to the input stage, only. Q13/14 won't live one second.) Do like you'd do with a real circuit: follow the signal.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: how can i make the set up work?

Comment: First get the input stage right: what is the idea with Q13& Q14? I can see a so-so current mirror in Q5&Q7 - what is the idea with R1& Q6? Then add one stage at a time.

Comment: q3 and q4 is the amplifier circuit

Comment: r1 is the emitter voltage to make the current match and  q6 is part of the current mirror circuit

Comment: q13 and q14 is the differential pair

Comment: Q3&Q4 are not in the input stage. Q13&Q14 are *not* the differential pair.

Comment: Q13 and Q14 is part of the cascoded differential pair

Comment: Q3 and Q4 is the high gain amplifier

Comment: *Q3 and Q4 is the [2nd stage] high gain amplifier* true (well, not so high gain, and lacking a power supply). *Q13 and Q14 is part of the [cascode(?)] differential pair* Those are no cascode configurations. I suggest starting with a simple differential pair with collector resistors, and continuing from there.

Answer (score 1):

You put 55V across the BE of Q13 and Q14.  I don't think that the simulation can accurately predict just how they are going to explode.

Comment: I tried with lower bias voltage  the output is a DC voltage

Comment: You don't put a "bias voltage" across BE: the characteristics of the BE diode are too steep to have this make sense except for very narrow exceptions like the special case of a current mirror where you have a thermally matched twin as a reference for the I/V relation with a given I.  And then, the BE voltage will end up between 0.6V and 0.7V.

Comment: I tried to use a cascoded differential pair

Comment: @qwerty Maybe you want to replace V1 with a current source (namely with an infinite rather than a zero internal resistance).  But it's hard to tell.  Also, the Q3/R4/R5/Q9 rail needs to get positive voltage somewhere.  This looks like something patched together that looks like something you saw elsewhere.

Comment: I didn't connect q13 and q3 and yeah I looked for a cascoded differential pair circuit to improve bandwidth

Comment: I tried another circuit  thanks for the help